# Taking a picture from user's webcam a la Facebook

Tags: flash, camera, webcam

i didn't find a recent question so somethign might have changed:

there is any widget, ready to use, to integrate with my website in order for my users to take a picture of themselves ala Facebook when they register to my site? i guess is Flash/flex based

thanks

Comment: why does this get voted down?

Comment: Not sure why my response wasn't accepted. I gave examples on how to build it and a commercial widget to achieve just what you wanted.

Comment: All i can do is vote you up back to 0.. not very fair though. Shouldn't be allowed to vote down without giving a reason why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't know of a widget, but it's not too tough to write something like this... access the camera, save image to a bitmapdata object, use as3corelib to encode it to jpeg (http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)and post it to your server using PHP or other middleware script.

This tutorial gets you pretty close to where you want to be:
http:// www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/quickstart/articles/jpeg_file_upload.html

If you don't want to write your own, you could always buy a component:
http://www.buystockflash.com/Take-My-Picture-v1.0-/-WebCam/flash-animation-251.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Userbooth.  It uses actionscript and php.  Opensource and it's free.

http://www.userbooth.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add "accept" attribute to file upload control. It will launch photo application on phone. Tested with Google Chrome browser on Android platform.

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
```